# How to cycle views in an Horizontal View Pager implementation in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Does anyone has an idea how to cycle views in an horizontal view pager in Android. Let's say we have 5 views, and the first view is selected right now, the 5th view should be on the left and the 2nd view should be on the right. I should be able to move to the 2nd/5th by swiping to the left/right respectively.

Comment: use inteface onpgaeChangeListener.
It has method(onPageScrolled) that will tell you.
@Override
 public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
   int positionOffsetPixels)

Answer (score 1):

A custom PagerAdapter should do the trick.

See step-by-step help for horizontal view pager here:
http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/354-android-ui-horizontal-view-pager